# How to extend Jest mock?

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

In my unit tests (written in Typescript, run by Jest), I want to mock two classes that share common functionality.  For instance they both have `tick()` and `getTicks()` methods.  My Jest mocks currently duplicates code to accomplish this, like so:

```js
const mock1 = jest.fn(() => {
  let ticks = 0;

  return {
    tick: jest.fn(() => {ticks++; }),
    getTicks: jest.fn(() => ticks),
    doSomething: jest.fn()
  }
});

const mock2 = jest.fn(() => {
  let ticks = 0;

  return {
    tick: jest.fn(() => {ticks++; }),
    getTicks: jest.fn(() => ticks),
    doAnotherThing: jest.fn()
  }
});
```

Now I can do:

```js
const mock1Instance = new mock1();
const mock2Instance = new mock2();
mock1Instance.tick();
mock2Instance.getTicks();
```

But the duplication seems stupid.  Is there a way for me to declare a base mock, and just extend from it, like:

```js
const baseMock = jest.fn(() => {
  let ticks = 0;

  return {
    tick: jest.fn(() => {ticks++; }),
    getTicks: jest.fn(() => ticks),
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your baseMock looks like this:

```
const baseMock = () => jest.fn(() => {
  let ticks = 0;

  return {
    tick: jest.fn(() => {ticks++; }),
    getTicks: jest.fn(() => ticks),
  }
});
```

you can create new objects with the baseMock properties and the required new properties:

```
const mock1Instance = {
  // note that new is not needed
  ...baseMock(),
  doSomething: jest.fn()
};

const mock2Instance = {
  ...baseMock(),
  doAnotherThing: jest.fn()
};
```

Or you can create it from the baseMock and assign it's property

```
const mock1Instance = baseMock();
mock1Instance.doSomething = jest.fn();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently doing something like this and it seems to work (at least tests don't fail), but I'd like to hear better answers:

```js
const baseMock = jest.fn(() => {
  let ticks = 0;

  return {
    tick: jest.fn(() => {ticks++; }),
    getTicks: jest.fn(() => ticks),
  }
});

const mock1 = jest.fn(() => {
  return {
    ...new baseMock(),
    doSomething: jest.fn()
  }
});

const mock2 = jest.fn(() => {
  return {
    ...new baseMock(),
    doAnotherThing: jest.fn()
  }
});

const mockInstance = new mock1();
mockInstance.tick(); // works ok
```